# Can pyspark.sql.functions.udf distribute a .py module to the worker nodes?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, udf

I use `pyspark.sql.functions.udf` to define a UDF that uses a class imported from a .py module written by me.

```
from czech_simple_stemmer import CzechSimpleStemmer #this is my class in my module
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
...some code here...

def clean_one_raw_doc(my_raw_doc):
    ... calls something from CzechSimpleStemmer ...

udf_clean_one_raw_doc = udf(clean_one_raw_doc, StringType())
```

When I call

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM mytable").withColumn("output_text", udf_clean_one_raw_doc("input_text"))
```

I get a typical huge error message where probably this is the relevant part:

```
File "/data2/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/ja063930/appcache/application_1472572954011_132777/container_e23_1472572954011_132777_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 431, in loads
return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ImportError: No module named 'czech_simple_stemmer'
```

Do I understand it correctly that pyspark distributes `udf_clean_one_raw_doc` to all the worker nodes but `czech_simple_stemmer.py` is missing there in the nodes' python installations (being present only on the edge node where I run the spark driver)?

And if yes, is there any way how I could tell pyspark to distribute this module too? I guess I could probably copy manually `czech_simple_stemmer.py` to all the nodes' pythons but 1) I don't have the admin access to the nodes, and 2) even if I beg the admin to put it there and he does it, then in case I need to do some tuning to the module itself, he'd probably kill me.

Comment: `SparkContext.addPyFile`

Comment: SparkContext.addPyFile("module.py") ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SparkContext.addPyFile("my_module.py") will do it.

Answer (score 0):

from the spark-submit [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/submitting-applications.html)

> For Python, you can use the --py-files argument of spark-submit to add
>   .py, .zip or .egg files to be distributed with your application. If
>   you depend on multiple Python files we recommend packaging them into a
>   .zip or .egg.